# Not able to fetch mongo result correctly for array inside a document

Tags: mongodb

```
{  
   "_id":ObjectId("570404d3b4aefafb2d975e49"),
   "timeStamp":NumberLong(1459881168860),
   "activityMessages":null,
   "oldLocation":null,
   "changeType":"ContainerCreated",
   "userId":"naveen",
   "newLocation":"L1-500",
   "itemHistory":[  
      {  
         "userId":null,
         "timeStamp":null,
         "oldLocation":null,
         "newLocation":null,
         "changeType":"ItemAdded",
         "activityMessages":null,
         "itemNumber":325136,
         "purchCompanyId":1003,
         "poNum":"100",
         "oldQty":NumberLong(0),
         "newQty":NumberLong(100),
         "inventoryStatus":"Received"
      },
      {  
         "userId":null,
         "timeStamp":null,
         "oldLocation":null,
         "newLocation":null,
         "changeType":"ItemAdded",
         "activityMessages":null,
         "itemNumber":325136,
         "purchCompanyId":1003,
         "poNum":"100",
         "oldQty":NumberLong(0),
         "newQty":NumberLong(2000),
         "inventoryStatus":"Frozen"
      },
      {  
         "userId":null,
         "timeStamp":null,
         "oldLocation":null,
         "newLocation":null,
         "changeType":"ItemAdded",
         "activityMessages":null,
         "itemNumber":88888,
         "purchCompanyId":1003,
         "poNum":"101",
         "oldQty":NumberLong(0),
         "newQty":NumberLong(200),
         "inventoryStatus":"Claims"
      }
   }
```

This is my typical Mongo document. On querying for a given item number in a given timestamp range with the query:

```
{ "timeStamp" :  { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , "itemHistory.itemNumber" : 325136}
```

I am getting the correct response ! However while searching for the itemNumber 88888, I am not getting any response for the same query.

```
{ "timeStamp" :  { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , "itemHistory.itemNumber" : 88888}
```

The following query works just fine :

```
{ "timeStamp" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , "itemHistory" : {"$elemMatch":{"itemNumber":112}}}
```

Response:

```
Fetched 0 records
```

This has made me wonder if only the first element of the array inside a document is being picked up while matching the query conditions. I have tried a bunch of other queries, nothing seems to be working.

I need the entire document to be returned which contains the given itemNumber!

TIA

Comment: This is a guaranteed typo in your real code. Check it again. It's not a bug or anything like that. You simply will have typed a field name or collection or something incorrectly. Cannot reproduce. Second query given here matches the document just like it should.

Comment: { "timeStamp" : { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , "itemHistory" : {"$elemMatch":{"itemNumber":112}}} this query works. There is no typo.

Comment: `{ "timeStamp" :  { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , "itemHistory.itemNumber" : 88888 }` works perfectly on the data you presented in this question. I know because I copied the document into a collection and then ran the query. You only **ever** need `$elemMatch` when you need to match "two or more conditions" on properties within an array. That is it's usage and nothing else.

Comment: I am using informix no sql. No mongoDB directly. Have a mongo listener as the middleware maybe that is why there is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed both types of queries with and without `elemMatch` and both fetched correct results.

```
db.collection.find({
   "timeStamp" :  { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , 
   "itemHistory.itemNumber" : 88888
})

db.collection.find({
  "timeStamp" :  { "$gte" : 0 , "$lte" : 1459933945543} , 
  "itemHistory" :{$elemMatch:{itemNumber: 88888}}
})
```

Result (Full document is omitted for brevity):

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("570500508eb3259244949d82"), 
    "timeStamp" : 1459881168860, 
    "activityMessages" : null, 
    "oldLocation" : null, 
    "changeType" : "ContainerCreated", 
    "userId" : "naveen", 
    "newLocation" : "L1-500", 
    "itemHistory" : [
        {
            "userId" : null, 
            "timeStamp" : null, 
            "oldLocation" : null, 
            "newLocation" : null, 
            "changeType" : "ItemAdded", 
            "activityMessages" : null, 
            "itemNumber" : 88888.0, 
            "purchCompanyId" : 1003.0, 
            "poNum" : "101", 
            "oldQty" : 0, 
            "newQty" : 200, 
            "inventoryStatus" : "Claims"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```